# How to find all references to variables of a given type in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am working on changing the way `DateTime` variables are handled in the project (an ASP MVC 5 website,) and I need to find all the usages of variables that are of type DateTime (at least the ones in the views.)  These variables probably all have date or time somewhere in their names, but they are *not* guaranteed to.  For instance, it could be called anniversary or holiday.

Manually, I would have to find each `DateTime` in the model, then find usages on each one of those variables.  It's certainly possible, but a lot more error-prone.  Is there any way to find references to variables of a given type (in my case DateTime) in a given project/solution?

---

EXAMPLE: 
I have a model object with a DateTime property:

```
public DateTime Anniversary { get; set; }
```

Then I render that property in a couple different partial views:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Anniversary)
```

or

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Anniversary, new { @class = "important date emphasis" })
```

I would want to find both of the examples in the view because they *reference* a DateTime variable, even though they are not called DateTime.

Comment: Do you use ReSharper?

Comment: I do.  I've tried exploring the Find Usages Advanced option, but it didn't seem to provide the functionality I was looking for.  Is there another way?

Comment: Find Usages on DateTime should do the trick then.

Comment: not sure if I understand you correctly, but have you tried to right click on the data type DateTime and select find all references?

Comment: @NKD, the issue is different.  I could find all the datetime variables, but that's not quite what I want.  I want to find all the times a DateTime variable is used (in *.cshtml files).  I could find usages for each DateTime variable one at a time, but there are lots, and I might miss some.  I'm assuming that find references is the same as find usages, since I don't have the former in my context menu.

Comment: @Drewmate ah got it! mm... I don't know the answer to this one. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Resharper has an advanced search feature that does what you need. See [Finding Usages of Related Entities](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp80/Navigation_and_Search__Finding_Usages__Finding_Usages_Advanced.html)

Comment: I've tried 'Find Usages Advanced' and it doesn't find the usages of DateTime variables, just their declarations.  I've tried it with the Usages, Usages of members, Textual occurrences and Dynamic references options, and none find the usage of a plain DateTime variable in my views.  I'll amend my question with an example.

Answer (score -2):

I would go the "hard" way. Search for all occurrence of DateTime in the Project/Solution. That will show me where such variables are.

Otherwise, write an Extension (helper) function for the DateTime class to do what I need to get done.

Good luck